# Need to set the width of a parent div dynamically based on the width of a ul

Tags: jquery

I've got a subnav on my site which is horizontal and I need to center it in the layout. Every subnav has a differnt number of elements so I need to calculate the width of the UL and then add it to the wrapping div so it will center properly.

Here is my html

```
<div id="subNav">
<ul id="navsub_761243_795431">
<li><a href="/Asset/RIA">Why Choose a RIA</a></li>
<li><a href="/Asset/HowWeOperate">How We Operate</a></li>
<li><a href="/Asset/ethicalinvesting">Ethical Investing</a></li>
<li><a href="/Asset/IndependentCustodian.htm">Independent Custodian</a></li>
<li><a href="/Quest/home">Insure Quest</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Sometimes the above list will be 2 elements, sometimes 1, sometimes 6.

Here is the jQuery I was messing with. It sits within a document ready function.

```
$("#subNav").css("width", $("#subNav ul").children("li").innerWidth());
```

This will give me the width of one element, not the sum of all of them. Any help is greatly appreciated!.

Comment: or you could just do it with css...

Comment: @meo I don't believe you can do this specific thing in just css.  The problem is that the ul's width is dynamic as it's list items are dynamic.  Since the div is a block level element it will expand to fill it's container.  In order to center the div (note not the ul) you would need to constrain it's width.  Depending on how dynamic the ul is the poster may not have the min/max values necessary to do this with just css

Comment: you can, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You would use this to get the rendered width of the ul:

```
$("#subNav").css("width", $("#subNav ul:first").width() + "px");
```

Forgot the "px" at the end.

Explaination: The rendered width of the ul will be equal to the sum of all the list item widths and this will include any margin and padding adjustments for the list items.  I don't believe jquery's .width() includes margin's or padding on the element you call it on (in this case the ul) so you may have to take that into account.

EDIT:  Changed selector so that it will only select the first ul encountered which in this example would be the outer ul (in the case of nested lists)

Comment: This works most of the time. When there is only one element, the width is 850px wide. It works if I target a specific ID. When I target the nested UL, the math is not accurate. Any ideas?

Comment: Ack changed because your comment explains it.  If you have more than one ul in the container (such as in the case of a nested ul) you need to make sure you only select the first ul you hit which should be the outer ul.  changing answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the previous answer is adequate. Just for reference, you have to specify the selector to get specific children. Then you could find the max value. However, this wouldn't get the width of the parent, but the max width of it's children.

You could specify with classes.
`<ul class="level-1">

  <li class="item-i">I</li>

  <li class="item-ii">II 
</ul>`

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

do it with css: http://jsfiddle.net/yW8mq/2/

edit: as you wrote in your comment you need to center the div also. So do the same thing i did to the UL to the div

Comment: then you can still do it with inline and make the next child element block... Or use the ie inline block hack, using inline and setting the element zoom to 1. http://grasshopperpebbles.com/css/css-inline-block-ie7-hack/ (zoom 1 fixes anything in ie :) ) Still better then to do it with js

Comment: I generally feel that it is better to use a little javascript than to start using browser specific hacks.  I should clarify my above comment that I don't think it can be done with css without resorting to hacks

Comment: Then you just feel wrong. No one told him to use a browserspecific hack! He can still insert a conditional CSS file to fix that. Something when wrong in your project whent you need to fix up your design with JS...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/nbzN3/

`JS:`

```
$.each($('.subNav ul').children(), function(i) {
    computedWidth += $('.subNav ul').children().eq(i).outerWidth();
});

$('.subNav:visible ul').width(computedWidth+10);
```

`HTML:`

```
<div id="subNav1" class="subNav">
    <ul id="navsub_761243_795431">
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1-4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 1-5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```